# Connect k8s cluster with azure api mangement

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I setup a kubernetes cluster on Azure, and I want to host REST Api using Azure API management.

I have create a deployment, service(Type: ClusterIP) in kubernetes, and they both seems to be running fine.

I like to expose REST Api to internet using Azure API management.

My question is:
Whats the most cost effective, and safest way to expose the API ?

I have gone through few articles which dictate to create service as internal load-balancer or NodePort but seems like those are not cost effective.

Although I did created the internal load balance which gives me external-ip but APIM can't excess.

All the kubernetes and Azure gurus, please provide 2 cents and help me!

In below picture, RED color arrow is what I am trying to figure out.
[image]

Comment: You could create the APIM and add an empty API following the steps in [Create an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/add-api-manually#create-an-api), then you can add the API backend with the URL that the AKS expose for you.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to setup an [Ingress Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network).  There is a good blog post [here](https://pumpingco.de/blog/control-ingress-to-aks-with-azure-api-management) that lays out the same scenario you described and walks you through setting it up.

Our docs on creating an Ingress Controller can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls).

Comment: Thanks, I did the similar installation using internal loadbalancer, but the problem with these implementation is that you need to add the api manually. However that I solved by importing the swagger.json file from my local to portal and change the URL from localhost to AKS EXTERNAL-IP

Comment: I am still looking for a better solution in terms of DevOps and azure costing.